# How Localizing media (sound) Android App

Tags: java, android, eclipse, localization, resources

I create Home page and put in it three imageview with flag for(Arabic,English,Frensh)language.user can select any language (Arabic,English,Frensh),and then go to next page which I put picture of apple fruit and button to play sound :
I add three sound to raw folder in resources :

```
raw:
apple.mp3
apple_en.mp3
apple_fr.mp3
```

when user click play button he must listen to sound in language which he select in home page.

I am new in android and I need help to know how I can localizing sound ,I can localizing string ,but sound I do not know

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the [introductory tour](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tour). Stackoverflow is neither a free coding nor a free consulting service. It is aimed at helping you with **your** code. Please show us what you tried so far. Please read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful.

Comment: I want to add picture of fruits and when user click to listen the name of fruit ,he should listen  to sound in language which he select in home page,in home page there is three language french, english, arabic,I do that for string but for sound i don't know how I do it

Comment: how Localizing sound(media) in android application

Answer (score 0):

For sound localisation just create a raw directory for each language and put inside the sound translated, for example, french : raw-fr, spanish :raw-es